# Poedit: Failed to load extracted catalog

Tags: php, wordpress, poedit

I'm working on an existing WP plugin (wpc catalogue) and I'm finished with my customizations. No I tried to translate the additional items using poEdit. When trying to parse the php source I'm getting this error:
Failed to load extracted catalog.

But I can't fix it, there is no explanation anywhere and I have no idea, what causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

Think finally I found the solution:

try to add in catalog / properties /keywords all keywords you use in your source code like __ or _

But apart that, PoEdit is partially strange...

Comment: Speaking of strange, so is asking for help with some application on SO instead of going to *its own* support or mailing list, where I’d be able to help you. It seems you did hit some bug in some version of Poedit that should be fixed and I’d love to do just that, but there’s unfortunately too little information here to make sense of what’s going on. If you could email help@poedit.net directly with more info (see e.g. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html), that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think, there is no bug I found. Speaking of 'strange' means imo the workflow isn't such clear as I expected. Maybe some people ( me included) needs a tutorial how to start up a new translation and futher more explanation how the files (mo, po, pot) work togehter. The main problem in this case was that I'm not able to find help or more information about this error message.Thanks, Olaf

Comment: Go to *Help->GNU gettext Manual* and read through it - it’s not that the explanation of how things work together isn’t there, it’s that you didn’t read it :( Also, something as simple as googling “poedit tutorial” or “poedit <something> tutorial” (e.g. “wordpress”) yields tons of articles. As for your other comment, I don’t know how can you be sure you didn’t find a bug, but the point was something else: that article is not only about “bugs”, but more generally about *describing things well* and it applies to to this SO question, which is extremely lacking in detail.